# Looping through properties of a class

Tags: vb.net

I use the following loop for looping through the properties of my class:

```
For Each prop As PropertyInfo In gData.GetType.GetProperties
                ...do something
Next
```

This are my properties in the class:

```
Public Property ID As String
    Public Property CC As Integer
    Public Property REP As New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String))
    Public Property DAT As New Dictionary(Of String, Int16())
    Public Property MIB As New Dictionary(Of String, ArrayList)
    Public Property PDF As Byte()
```

I will ignore the property "CC", but I want to find out the content of the properties REP, DAT and MIB. The property PDF I only check for content.

My problem is, that I have no idea how to access e.g. REP.

REP is, as you can see, a dictionary. The content of the dict can be the following:

1. only the string "HH"
2. only the string "Rel"
3. both strings

Depending on the content of the different properties I build a checksum.

How can I get the keys of the properties, so how can I check if the key "HH" of the property REP exists?

Comment: there are actually really good examples on how to loop thru and find properties you can do it with Reflection or you can do it creating a method using Generics or creating your own method ...do a simple and quick google search

Comment: REP is a property (as dictionary). I only want to access the keys of this property. The values doesn't matter.

Comment: I tried with prop.PropertyType.GetFields, but with no success. I have no idea what .net function I have to use, to get access to the keys of e.g. the property "REP".

Comment: It's not clear to me why you even need to loop at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
if gData.REP.ContainsKey("HH") then 
   'Blah blah
End If
```